# Unable to suspend an instance of a URLSessionDataTask

Tags: swift, concurrency, uikit, suspend

I am instantiating a `URLSessionDataTask` that downloads hundreds of thumbnail images and stuffs them into an array.  Each entry in the array is used to populate a cell in a `UITableView` instance.  It works exactly as expected.

However, I want to give the user the opportunity to click on a cell and initiate a second instance of a `URLSessionDataTask` in an effort to download additional details associated with that thumbnail. And I don't want the user to wait until the first data task finishes.

That's where the problem lies.  The second `URLSessionDataTask` instance doesn't retrieve the data I need until the first `URLSessionDataTask` instance *completes*.  I guess I don't understand this since my understanding is that the first task is an asynchronous background task.

So I tried a workaround such that when the user clicks on a cell to grab the detail information I would suspend the first task, download the detail info and then resume the first task.

I want to do something roughly like this:

```
var firstTask = callThumbnailServer(queryString: createHTTPQueryString())

func userAsksForDetails() {
   firstTask.suspend()
   var secondTask = callDetailServer(queryString: createHTTPQueryString())
   firstTask.resume()
}
```

But `firstTask.suspend()` appears to have no effect.  Now, `firstTask.cancel()` *does* successfully *cancel* the first task, but I don't want to cancel, I want to suspend/resume.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Why does the second data task appear not to run until the first one completes?
2. Why does cancel() work but suspend() does not?

Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm just starting with UIKit and Swift.

Comment: "I am instantiating a URLSessionDataTask"  Where?

Comment: This is resolved now.  Thanks to [link](https://dev.to/shawonashraf/loading-images-from-urls-in-swift-without-urlsession-127g).  Turns out I had a tight loop inside my asynchronous call to the server that was downloading the images using a synchronous mechanism (the "easy way" as described in the link).  Once I switched to an asynchronous mechanism, everything was .resolved